# JS add property to object via function call from construcator

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I can't figure out why the following code:

```
 function Foo() {
    this.a = "a";                               
    this.c = add();
}
var add = function() {
    this.b = "added";
}

obj2 = new Foo();
alert("obj2.b is " + obj2.b); //obj2.b is Undefined
```

Won't create 'b' property to obj2 while this code:

```
function Foo() {
    this.a = "a";                               
    this.func1 = add;
    this.c = this.func1();
}
var add = function() {
    this.b = "added";
}

obj2 = new Foo();
alert("obj2.b is " + obj2.b); // obj2.b is added
```

Will create the 'b' property.
I'm new to JS, I tried reading about using function as constructor and basicly I got the idea but I guess there is still something I'm missing.
Thank you,
Noam

Comment: The value of `this` is set based on *how* a function is called. If you call a function as a property of an object, `this` in the function becomes the object.

Answer (score 3):

> the value of this is determined by how a function is called.

If no caller, then `this` will point to default/global scope(window).

If you need to pass context to another function, you should use one of following: `.apply`, `.bind`

#### Sample

```js
function Foo() {
    this.a = "a";                               
    this.c = add.apply(this);
}
var add = function() {
    this.b = "added";
}

obj2 = new Foo();
console.log("obj2.b is " + obj2.b); //obj2.b is Undefined
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please find updates and if something is missing or incorrect, please point it out.

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)